# Angular ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1 Open modal Dialog Set focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, focus

I'm currently playing with angular, and in particular angular with bootstrap module (who can live without bootstrap nowadays?).

In any case, does anybody have a clean solution for seting focus on an input field within a new modal dialog that is popped open?
This basic feature seems not to be supported out of the box.
I thought I could hook up in the "opened" future - but it seems to get called to early.

So, when you open a modal instance - e.g.

```
$modal.open({
                "templateUrl": 'myModalContent.html',
                "controller" : 'modalInstanceCtrl',
                "size": size,
                "resolve" : {
                    "items": function () {
                        return $scope.items;
                    }
                }
            });
```

You then can use the modal instance with something like broadcast an even:

```
 modalInstance.opened.then(function(){
                $rootScope.$broadcast(myNewDirectiveBootstrapConfig.events.modalInstanceOpened
                        , modalInstance);
            });
```

Now the input element that I want to focus upon would be angular enhanced with a directive.

```
<label for="popupTitle">Title:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="popupTitle"
       ng-required="true"
       ng-model="popup.title"
       ng-minlength="1"
       newdirective-modal-focus
       >
```

And directive code would be something none intrusive and independent of the page logic. You would ideally only consume the event API and your non intrusive directive get called and do the focus magic.

```
angular.module('newDirectivesModule', [])
.constant('myNewDirectiveBootstrapConfig', {
    events: {
        modalInstanceOpened : "modalInstanceOpened"
    }
})
.directive('newdirectiveModalFocus', ['myNewDirectiveBootstrapConfig',    
function (myNewDirectiveBootstrapConfig) {
    return {
      restrict:'A', // process compile directive only on element attributes


       link: function(scope, elm, attr) {             
             scope.$watch(function(){return elm.is(":visible");}, function(value) {
                 if(elm.is(":visible")){
                     elm.focus();                         
                 }                   
             });

             scope.$on(myNewDirectiveBootstrapConfig.events.modalInstanceOpened, function(event, data) {
                 if(elm.is(":visible")){
                     elm.focus();
                 }                   
             });                                  
        }          
    };
}]);
```

You see in the code that i've played with different watch scenarios.
The reality is , the directive code is getting called to son.
The opened.then future seems to be publishing the event stating that the model is open before you actually see the modal dialog floating on the screen.
The input element is told to be set on focus - but apprently to soon, if I debug it is still in the background when the focus() gets called.
IT is visible, in the sense that you can do a find for in the dom of the page and in the sense that if you ask JQuery(":visible") dom element it is indeed visible. But it is still invisible to the eye.

I've seen somewhere else an approach that was totally different from mine, did not rely on events and depend on an attribute value changing from true to false.
I did not like the apporach at all because it was too coupled with the business logic of the page, which I dislike and refuse as a solution.

A solution for this should rely solely on the fact that the modal dialog will only have in its body a single input element anootated with the set focus on me please directive and be as decoupled as possible from page logic.

Ideally this should be a supported feature by bootsrap angular itself, sadly it seems not to be, but since we have to - in any case - use APIs to oepn dialogs and close them, we should just be able to extend this step in a cross cuting clean manner to get the focus feature in.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 3):

I use different way of directive for focus `post link` to be sure that element is rendered (no matter modal or not):

```
app.directive('focusMe',
    ['$timeout',
        function ($timeout) {
            return {
                link: {
                    pre: function preLink(scope, element, attr) {
                      // ...
                    },
                    post: function postLink(scope, element, attr) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            element[0].focus();
                        }, 0);


                    }
                }
            }
        }]);
```

So the input should look like:

```
<input type="text" 
       focus-me
       class="form-control" id="popupTitle"
       ng-required="true"
       ng-model="popup.title"
       ng-minlength="1">
```

---

Demo in <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UaiwQmkl7hSCuQSH2L6X?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Hi, I am giving you the fingers up on the suggestion, but I do not think the solution is perfect. The solution you provided works in your test page apprently. On mine, I had to put a 200 ms timeout. The timeout 0 did not work porperly, and in yours, I debugged the example.js, and the moment you set the focus() on the element, it is still not visible the modal. And I wonder if you are geting lucky on the timing. Because most likely on mine - the focus changes between the time i set the focus and the time the modal is actually fully visible. Set a breakpoint on your focus function and c.

Comment: And since on my case, I had to put a timeout of 200 ms I of course do not like the solution because it is not deterministic behaviour. I will try to see if I find out who is the element that in the end gets the focus when mine suffers a focus() but is not focused on. Sombody else must be getting it - e,g a submit button or such. I will c... But I like the fact that I can discard the event, so your solution is a lot less complex than mine. Which is always nice. the Simpler the better.

Comment: @99Sono did u try to use `$timeout` without value? like: `$timeout(function () {
                            element[0].focus();
                        });`

Comment: @99Sono the question is how do you render the modal? can u change plunker I porvided with reproduce the issue?

Comment: I open the model pretty much like you do, based on the snippet from the boostrap  documentation. I added some dummy extra data model ('items') that came in my snippet, but in your case the focus is wroking fine even with the ng- repeat. I have other components in the patch such angular tree. Nope, I will analyse my page. In any case, why do you need to use the timeout service if your timeout is set to 0?

Comment: Actually, yes, i was able to reproduce it in pluker.  http://plnkr.co/edit/dehbWEgdPPaFtqgl5lKA?p=preview   Main changes: (1) Upgrade bootstrap css to 3.3.1 and upgrade angular js 1.3.8 if I am not mistaken. That was it. - Also had to fix the controller definitions to go under .controller() instead of as global variables. And again, I ask : if the code is deterministic - why would you use the timer service in the post link ? By the way, if the directive does nothing in the pre link - which is the case, it is less code to just define link : function() instead of object with post link.